# In my gs code javascript function return the value like (300100100120) instead of 620

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here is the code that I'm using. Normally show the result correct but in some cases(not all) it shows the scattered values like 1800100100 or 300100100120 or something like that.

```
function totalcharge(closer,currentmonth){
  var SHEET_NAME = 'Sales';
  var Scoresheet = 'Score';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  //Getting the range of the sheet to be covered.
  var values = sheet.getRange("A1:AL2500").getValues();
  var closer; var currentmonth;
  var ttlcharge=0;
  for (var i in values) {
    if (values[i][24] == closer && values[i][28] == currentmonth) {
      ttlcharge += values[i][26];
    }
  }
   var result = ttlcharge;
  return result ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I thought that in your case, the reason of issue might be that a part of cells is the string type. In order to use the values retrieved by `getValues` as the number type, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
ttlcharge += values[i][26];
```

#### To:

```
ttlcharge += Number(values[i][26]);
```

or

```
ttlcharge += values[i][26] * 1;
```

#### Reference:

- [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)

Comment: no, it doesn't work. But I have resolved the problem already. Thanks though.

Comment: I just added && values[i][26] != "";   to 
 if (values[i][24] == closer && values[i][28] == currentmonth && values[i][26] != "";)
and it's working fine now.

Comment: @Arslan Farooq Thank you for replying and adding more information. I'm glad your issue was resolved.